# Jquery animate with inline-block divs not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Can anybody enlighten me on what I have wrong or why this code isn't working? I think it is obvious what I am trying but the animate seems to pull down the other divs. I can't get my head around what is happening!

```js
$("#optionDoors").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: "50px",
        lineHeight: "50px"
    });     
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

div#mainContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 950px;
    height: 1000px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    margin: 0px auto;
}   

#productChoice {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#productChoice div {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 236.5px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#productChoice div:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='mainContainer'>
    <div id='productChoice'>    
        <div id='optionDoors'>
            <span>Option1</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Option2</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Option3</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Option4</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example here so it's clear what is happening... https://jsfiddle.net/L6zkxzpn/

Comment: explain more to make it obvious . Which `div` is pulled down ? What is the initial height of `optionDoors` ?

Comment: I will link to a working example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `#productChoice div` has the style `vertical-align: middle;` set. So when you increase the size of the first div, all of the others re-align themselves downwards because #productChoice has increased in size to cater for its bigger first child.

Change this style to `vertical-align: top;` to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks! It's always something obvious!

Comment: Just curious though, what is the default alignment? Because taking out the vertical-align property:value has the same effect as before, so does this mean if it isn't set it's default is "middle"?

Comment: Default is baseline